# How to fix: When clicking my internal link the page is blank

Tags: html

[here is a screenshot of what I'm working with hopefully it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xAfx.png)I am currently trying to insert an internal link on my "site" to link to another file in my directory.

```
<html>

    <h1>Contact us</h1>
        <p>Phone: | Email: </p>
</html>
```

```
<a href="contact.html">contact us</a>
```

the first fence of code is the contact.html file I am trying to link and the second is what I am using to link.

I expect to click on the link and have it lead me to the "contact us" page but when I click the link it is blank.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you missed some of your code? I don't see any `<a>` tags

Comment: is better to show where the file locate to ease us to help u troubleshoot?

Comment: You are missing a `<body>` tag inside your `<html>` I know that is allowed in browsers, but still you can try to put it and check once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Go to contact

Normally it should work, if not lets see the directory on your system.
Something seems confusing on `img` folder

Comment: I think the user wants to link to another file as mentioned in the first line of question. This solution will just take him to a section of the same file.

Comment: He is not telling us where the file is located.

Comment: He has added a link to screenshot of the IDE. I guess the missing `<body>` tag could be the issue, but cannot ascertain.

Answer (score 0):

I go through your screenshot if the page on same directory, your code is good. Just try with:

`<a href="./Contact.html">Contact</a>`

this will work same way as above sometime browser doesn't read file.

Comment: Yes I've tried to use that as well and the page is still blank. I did add the <body> tag in the contact.html file as someone mentioned above and still the same results as well as with and without <!doctype> in the contact.html file. I'm following "the net ninja" tutorial on youtube but I can't tell what it is im doing wrong.